# GC и неуправляемый код

Tags: c#, сборщик-мусора

Я работают с OpenCL в C# через Cloo. Для серии вычислений я создаю массив из буферов:

```
ComputeKernel[] computeKernels = new ComputeKernel[TempsByStep.Count];
ComputeBuffer<double>[] Temps = new ComputeBuffer<double>[TempsByStep.Count];
ComputeBuffer<double>[] Steps = new ComputeBuffer<double>[TempsByStep.Count];
ComputeBuffer<double>[] Outputs = new ComputeBuffer<double>[TempsByStep.Count];
```

который инициализирую в цикле

```
for (int i = 0; i < TempsByStep.Count; i++)
{
    //создаем буферы обмена
    computeKernels[i] = CalculateJIntegralSingleStep.CreateKernel("CalcdJIntegral");
    Temps[i] = new ComputeBuffer<double>(Context,
        ComputeMemoryFlags.UseHostPointer | ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadOnly,
        TempsByStep[i].ToArray());
    Steps[i] = new ComputeBuffer<double>(Context
        , ComputeMemoryFlags.UseHostPointer | ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadOnly,
        new double[] { Accuracy[i] });
    output_buffer[i] = new double[TempsByStep[i].Count - 1];
    Count[i] = TempsByStep[i].Count - 1;
    Outputs[i] = new ComputeBuffer<double>(Context,
        ComputeMemoryFlags.UseHostPointer | ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadWrite,
       output_buffer[i]);
    //конфигурируем кернел
    computeKernels[i].SetMemoryArgument(1, Temps[i]);
    computeKernels[i].SetMemoryArgument(2, Steps[i]);
    computeKernels[i].SetMemoryArgument(3, Outputs[i]);
    //Блокируем удаление
    GC.KeepAlive(computeKernels[i]);
    GC.KeepAlive(Temps[i]);
    GC.KeepAlive(Steps[i]);
    GC.KeepAlive(Outputs[i]);
    GC.KeepAlive(output_buffer[i]);
    GC.KeepAlive(Count[i]);
}
```

после так же защищаю сами массивы

```
//Блокируем удаление
GC.KeepAlive(computeKernels);
GC.KeepAlive(Temps);
GC.KeepAlive(Steps);
GC.KeepAlive(Outputs);
```

И передаю в метод, который это использует с ref

```
return CalculateJF(variables[0], Count, ref computeKernels, ref Outputs, x);
```

в самом конце удаляю в цикле

```
for (int i = 0; i < TempsByStep.Count; i++)
{
    computeKernels[i].Dispose();
    Temps[i].Dispose();
    Steps[i].Dispose();
    Outputs[i].Dispose();
}
```

Проблема в том, что в 3 из 10 случаев программа через случайную итерацию расчета благополучно вылетает без какого то exception вообще. Код завершения намекает на "status stack buffer overrun", 0xc0000409.
Все попытки что либо исправить сводятся именно к этому участку кода. Я думаю, что GC удаляет объекты из памяти, т.к. например Steps больше нигде не фигурирует. KeepAlive помог, т.к. раньше вылетало с первого раза, но проблема как была, так и осталась. 
Как можно заставить GC игнорировать эти переменный до тех пор пока я сам не вызову Dispose?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема действительно оказалась с удалением объектов GC.
Объект, который может быть удален, нужно поместить в конструкцию, указанную тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005865/prevent-net-garbage-collection-for-short-period-of-time
Нужно очень тщательно выбирать код, который будет помещено в область с отключенным GC, т.к. случайная ошибка может вызвать stack overflow exception

Comment: А можно просто хранить нужные объекты в глобальных переменных (strong reference), и GC их не тронет.

Comment: Насколько я понял, при создании буфера Cloo копирует значения из указанной переменной, т.к. если менять значения в этой самой переменной, то OpenCl ведет расчет по первым указанным данным. Значения в буфере разные для разных расчетов, поэтому вариант не подходит.

Comment: Сколько не гуглил, не увидел, что кто-либо сталкивается с такой же проблемой, [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42282548/am-i-reusing-opencl-clooc-objects-correctly) и [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427951/how-do-i-reduce-the-overhead-of-buffer-creation-for-opencl-cloo-c), посмотрите, быть может нужно откорректировать подход к использованию API.